# Azure Subnet-to-Subnet Security Rules without Application Security Groups

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg, azure-vm

I'm trying to understand the Network Security Groups and Application Security Groups. What I'm trying to achieve is I have a basic set up as below.

[image]

In my vnet, I have 2 subnets which are front-end and back-end and I have 2 NSGs that each subnet is assigned to.

Let's say I decided to allow RDP requests on my "back-end" subnet only for requests coming from the "front-end" subnet and deny any other RDP requests coming from other subnets.

I know that if I create ASGs and assign the FrontEnd VM and BackEnd VM an application security group then I can create a rule on NSG which is to allow RDP request from one ASG to the other ASG to achieve this but if you have dozens of VMs in a subnet then you wouldn't want to waste time to assign an ASG to every VM.

Is there a way to define a rule on a subnet that allows specific requests coming from other subnets?

Answer (score 1):

create a rule and set the source to `VirtualNetwork` that will allow anyone from inside the Virtual Network (and peered ones) to send that type of traffic. If you want subnet granularity - you'd have to use subnet IP address ranges to allow\deny specific traffic patterns. You might also want to override the default rule to allow anything inside the virtual network

Comment: Yes I want subnet granularity. Is setting a subnet IP range on a NSG rule as source manually the only way? Cause in this case we have to type all IPs manually rather than selecting a subnet name

Comment: It appears that using subnet ip address / range is the only way to go right now.